# Getting all dark output image

Tags: matlab, histogram, local

If I remove the `uint8` when I'm giving the matrix `B` its size, I get an output that is overshadowed by a red plane. I've also added the `[]` in the `imshow(B, [])` to resolve the issue of the all dark output, but it doesn't help.

```
function myThirdAssignment(I,WindowSize,K0,K1,K2)

%if size(I,3)==1
 

 %[rows, columns, numberOfColorChannels] = size(I);
 
%elseif size(I,3)==3
    
x= im2double(imread(I));
%gray1=rgb2gray(x);
%[r, c, numberOfColorChannels] = size(gray1);
%end


if nargin==1 % If number of arguments of the function are equal to 1 then use 
             % the following default values for K0,K1,K2, & Window size.
    K0= 0.5;
    
    K1= 1;
    
    K2= 0.5;
    
    WindowSize=3;
end

figure(1); imshow(x); title('ORIGINAL IMAGE');
imwrite(x,'OriginalImage.bmp.bmp'); %writing data of original image in to current directory.

% GIVING B THE SAME ROWS AND COLUMS AS THE ORIGINAL IMAGE
[rows, columns, numberOfColorChannels] = size(x);
B = zeros(rows, columns, numberOfColorChannels, 'uint8');


% CALCULATING CEIL & FLOOR VALUES TO MAKE PROGRAM MORE GENERAL
p= ceil((WindowSize / 2)); %3/2= 1.5=2


s= floor((WindowSize / 2)); %3/2=1.5=1



        
        
        
        
           
            B(i,j)= 2*x(i,j);
            
        
        
        else
            B(i,j)= x(i,j);
        end
    
        %--------------------------------------------
        
    end


end

%RGB = cat(3, B, B, B);
figure(2);imshow(B, []); title('IMAGE AFTER LOCAL HISTOGRAM EQUALIZATION');
imwrite(B,'enhancedImage.jpeg.jpeg'); %writing data of enhanced image in to current directory

end
```

I used [this image](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcR5Z4Q67xqu3_2EuUmcRNpfSuCmVrIDZI_fbA&usqp=CAU) as input.

Comment: You're question is unclear, what are you trying to achieve ?  why is it not working ? Why are you removing something that broke your code ?

Comment: Just remove `uint8` from `B = zeros(rows, columns, numberOfColorChannels, 'uint8');` and you get _an_ image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here: a) the uint8 issue which you have solved already which converts double values into uint8 which rounds everything to 0 resulting in a dark image, and b) the resulting red image which occurs because you're only performing your local histogram equalization on the red channel of your input image x and your green and blue channels in your output image are zeros.

Change your code to this:

```
if avg <= K0*(meanIntensity) && (K1*(stdG) <= std) && (std <= K2*(stdG))
           % only enhance an area of defined window size when its mean/average is 
           % lesser than or equal to the mean of the image by some constant
           % K0 AND its standard deviation is lesser than the value of the
           % standard deviation by a constant K2 and greater than the
           % global standard deviation by a constant K1.
           
            B(i,j,1)= 2*x(i,j,1);
            B(i,j,2)= 2*x(i,j,2);
            B(i,j,3)= 2*x(i,j,3);
        
        
        else
            B(i,j,1)= x(i,j,1);
            B(i,j,2)= x(i,j,2);
            B(i,j,3)= x(i,j,3);
        end
```

Comment: omg this helped so much, but can you explain a bit further why you added these values of 1,2 and 3?

Comment: Your input image is a color image, which typically has 3 channels - R,G, and B. In your code [rows, columns, numberOfColorChannels] = size(x); the numberOfColorChannels will contain 3 because the image is in color. When you do your operations, you were doing it only on channel #1 which is the red channel resulting in a red image. Had you done it only on channel #2 you would have gotten a green image and so on. Doing it on all three gives you a color image result. You may want to do the operation differently for different channels, like compute mean intensity per channel etc.

Comment: To elaborate, your code as written would have worked perfectly if the input image was a grayscale image containing only two dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

`x` is double (`im2double`), meaning that its values are between 0 and 1.

You are storing it on a unsigned integer from 0-255, `B`. As a unsigned integer, it will crop all decimal places and round to the nearest int, which is 0. So `B(i,j)= x(i,j)` is always zero.

You may mean `B(i,j)= x(i,j)*255` ?

Or even better, just always operate on doubles, and then convert int before saving, if its a requirement.

Comment: ok so i removed the uint8 to make B double, but then when I output B, it comes out with a red filter over it.

Comment: im trying to get an output B that shows local histogram equalization for areas in the image  with bad contrasts

Comment: Not with a red filter, the image is just red. As you know, an image has 3 channels, R, G and B. You would need to modify your code to index a 3D matrix (`B(i,j,1)` is red, but `B(i,j,2)` is blue, etc). Your code simply is not designed for color images